# Why am I missing a factor of 1000?

Tags: communication

This is what I read from a text:

> The T1 system is used for wireline long-distance service in North America and is an excellent example of TDM. Speech from a telephone conversation is **sampled once every 125 msec** and **each sample is converted into eight bits** of digital data. Using this technique, a transmission **speed of 64,000 bits/sec is required** to transmit the speech.

If a signal is sampled every 125 msecs and it is converted to 8 bits of data, isn't it equal to total of 64 bits of sampled data per sec? Where does factor of 1000 come from?

Comment: It's obviously just a screwup.  Phone voice in this system is sampled at 8 kHz rate, which is 125 us period.

Comment: Think about it. Eight samples per second cannot reproduce speech! The bandwidth is limited to around 4Hz.

Answer (score 3):

That text has a typo. It should be 125 µsec.

Comment: Yes, the sample rate is 8kHz. 8kHz * 8bits = 64kbps

Comment: A typo because the µ key is too close to the m key? Ha! More like someone thinking that "m" is a suitable abbreviation for "micro".

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be that your reading a text from a geographic area where they use the comma (",") as a decimal point sign.

However, it's most likely the text is faulty and it should be "usec" or "µsec" instead of "msec". 125 milliseconds is very slow for a T-carrier!